# Why CListView dataProvider fails to manage the data received from Sphinx?

Tags: php, yii, sphinx, dataprovider

I use `Sphinx` to generate a list of needed `ID`'s. On this list of `ID`'s I apply `filters` using the `Sphinx` language and then I create and return a new CActiveDataProvider using the `Search` Model method;

[image example](http://content.screencast.com/users/flaviuspogacian/folders/Jing/media/7c4273a9-a784-4376-b206-5b9f5c9343ee/2013-02-07_1241.png)

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('model', array(
                    'criteria' => $criteria,
                    'pagination' => array(
                        'pageSize' => $this->pageSize,
                        'currentPage' => $this->cp_page - 1,
                    ),
                ));
```

In the view, now, I have:

```
<div class="search_result searchconright">
         <?php

                 $custom_pager_left = '
                <div class="pagetxt">

                <ul class="searchPager">
                    <li><span>View</span></li>
                    <li class="page"><a href="" class="page_search_limit">All</a></li>
                    <li class="page"><a href="" class="page_search_limit page_search_limit_active">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page"><a href="" class="page_search_limit page_search_limit_active">5</a></li>
                    <li class="page"><a href="" class="page_search_limit page_search_limit_active">24</a></li>
                    <li class="page"><a href="" class="page_search_limit">48</a></li>
                </ul>

                </div>
            ';

        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'ajaxUrl' => Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/employer/search'),
            'id'=>'listViewSearch',
            'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
            'template' => "{summary}\n{sorter}\n{items}\n<div style='float:left;width=700px;'>$custom_pager_left<div class='pagetxt'>{pager}</div></div>",
            'itemView' => '_index_post',
            'enablePagination' => true,
            'pager' => array(
                'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/clistview.css',
                'header' => false,
                'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',
                'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',
                'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            ),
            'summaryText' => '',
            'sortableAttributes' => array(
            ),
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
```

But this fails to work correctly, because if i click next, and the list end's, somehow, the ajax code does not reinitialize the url that is being send, it keeps on to concat with the old url until the url gets so big that the app crashes.

Shouldn't CListView verify if the data received exists? Sphinx could give a ID of a registration, that is no more there or inactive;

What's happening and how can i prevent this?

Comment: I think it might be something with pager rather than CListView. How does the *expanding* url looks like? It keeps adding pages, or?...

Comment: ClListView widget includes a pager; explain the term EXPANDING url ... i dont understand

Comment: Sorry, i meant that url in your question, where you mention ** it keeps on to concat with the old url until the url gets so big that the app crashes**. Does it add params like page/1/page/2/page/3?

Comment: no, it concats the old url with the new request url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found forum topic with some issues with `ajaxUrl` property and pagination. It looks like ajaxUrl is ignored by pagination. Weird, maybe thats the problem.

Here is this topic: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21886-problem-with-clistview-and-ajaxurl-property/

Notice that at last posts route is set on dataprovider rather than listview. Internally listview, or grid view, should pass ajaxUrl into dataprovider.

Here is how to manually setup route for pagination:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#route-detail

```
$dataprovider->pagination->route = 'site/index';
```

Also manually set params for pagination if some are used (including does coming with $_GET):
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#params-detail

```
$dataprovider->pagination->params = array('search' => 'Search string');
```

Im also not sure how `$custom_pager_left` link hrefs should be set?

Comment: for $custom_pager_left i have ajax code that catches the values and starts a process

Comment: so, after a long time, i read the docs from the pages you supplied, and yes, this is a yii issue; i needed to unset the $_GET, before creating the links again